# Cannot override h2 properties in CSS

Tags: css

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong here, I've positioned paragraphs and headings easily before but for some reason cannot move the paragraph 'After taking to the walking trails...' up closer to the h2 heading 'ladies beach local view'(both these are at the bottom of the linked page)

The problem seems to be in both the line-height and margin-bottom properties of the h2 heading tag so I've tried overriding both to reduce the gap - as can be seen in the CSS - but the gap remains. Any idea why the CSS is not fixing the gap ? Thanks

Here's the CSS I tried using:

```
.betta h2 {
margin-bottom: 0px;
font-weight: 300;
line-height: 1.00em;
letter-spacing: 1px;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 span {
margin-bottom:0px;
font-family:"Oswald", sans-serif;
font-weight:300;
line-height:1.00em;
letter-spacing:1px;
}
```

Here's the page link, the problem part is at the bottom of the page, thanks.

http://dbtest.destinationballybunion.ie/?page_id=4952

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have this margin-bototm:18px set here..

/wp-content/themes/pinboard/style.css line 120

I don't know if this is the same stylesheet which you are currently trying to use, but you can override it by using the same/more class/classes further down this same document; or, by including your desired stylesheet AFTER this one in your head.

Comment: That stylesheet is what you could call the default stylesheet for the Wordpress theme I'm using. I'm using a drag and drop builder called Virtual Composer that allows you to apply classes to divs etc. on the page. I've tried applying a more specific class than h2 .ie .betta h2 {...} which I though would override the default stylesheet but it hasn't.

Comment: You could always go into "/wp-content/themes/pinboard/style.css", and add your styles at the bottom of this document; that should override it. 

I see you say !important didn't work, and I don't actually see this stylesheet being included in your head so it's possible that it is being called with js and that is why it's being overridden - but without access it's somewhat guesswork! :)

Comment: In fact I've tried !important a few times and it never works. I added the margin-bottom change to the stylesheet as you said and it works fine now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the css located in the head section is not working properly, and therefore the !important isn't working (Even though there should be no need since it is located under the stylesheet call). However if you place the below code at the end of the style.css it works just fine.

```
.betta h2 {
   margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

I have also noticed you have several  sections in the head, perhaps it is what may be causing the conflict. I would suggest grouping them, and putting them in a seperate sheet and use the @import at the end of style.css, link of how to do so can be seen here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/@import

Comment: Yeah that works when added to styles.css, thanks and cheers for the link, there are four sources of CSS on the site which makes for a seriously messy situation. I'll be tidying up the CSS pretty soon.

Answer (score 0):

The problem, as it appears **now** on the site, is not to do with margin, but with line-height. Try set

`.betta h2 {
   line-height: 1;
}`

not `1em`.

Your HTML is also set up with a `span` inside of the `h2`.

The `h2` `line-height` base is being set by the `font-size: 60px;` which is applied to the `h2`, but the `span` is not mirroring this. Remove the `font-size` attribute from your `h2` if you'd like to adjust this.

You may also want to change the `verticle-align: baseline;` to `verticle-align: centre;` on the span.

Comment: I just realised this question is over 2 years old. Not sure how I got myself here.

Answer (score -1):

You can override by using `!important`. for example:

```
h2 {
  margin-bottom: 0px !important;
}
```

Comment: _Never_ use `!important` unless its the last possible solution.

Comment: For what it's worth I tried !important and that still doesn't get rid of the 18px margin !